# Is mezonot jealous of kiddush?

Tags: halacha, kiddush, mezonot-beracha

Should we cover plates of crackers and rogelach in a shul kiddush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good overview is provided [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/must-one-cover-mezonos-foods-that-are-on-the-table-during-kiddush/#_ftn10):

The starting point to understanding this concept is with Challah - i.e. we ensure the challos are covered whilst kiddush is said because of three reasons:

1. Honour of Shabbos - i.e. once Kiddush is made, the food is uncovered to show how it was brought to the table in honour of the Shabbos meal (see [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 271:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Magen Avraham 271:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.271.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Tur 271](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.271.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Tosafos Pesachim 100b s.v. שאין מביאין את השלחן אא"כ קידש](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.100b.2?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Pesachim.100b.2.3&lang2=bi))
2. Remembering the Mann - i.e. Just as the Mann was encased in a layer of dew above and below, so too we do with the challos. (Refer to [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 271:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Taz 271:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [M”B 271:41](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.271.41?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Tur 271](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.271.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Sefer HaTerumah 246](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaTerumah%2C_Simanim.246.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
3. Covering the "shame" of the bread - i.e. since the blessing of hamotzi is considered of greater precedence than hagefen, we cover the bread whilst making kiddush so as not to "shame" the bread. (See [Tur 271](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.271.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in name of Yerushalmi, [Rema 437:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.473.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [MA 299:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.299.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Aruch HaShulchan 299:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.299.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) etc.)

So this third point leads us to the question of covering for mezonos foods during kiddush, and as with most things, it is a machlokes.

Therefore:

> Some Poskim<sup>1</sup> rule that the Mezonos foods on the table are to be covered.<sup>2</sup> This especially applies if one plans to fulfill his Mitzvah of Makom Seuda with the eating of this Mezonos product.<sup>3</sup> Other Poskim<sup>4</sup>, however, rule that there is no need to cover foods other than Challos, even if one plans to eat Mezonos after Kiddush.<sup>5</sup> [Practically, if there are Challos on the table, then only the bread needs to be covered and there is no need to cover any of the other foods, including the Mezonos foods that are on the table.<sup>6</sup> If, however, there are no Challas on the table, and one plans to eat Mezonos after Kiddush, then one is to be stringent to cover it as rules the first opinion.<sup>7</sup> This, however, only applies if the Mezonos is made of wheat or barley, in which case it precedes the blessing of Hagafen. If, however it is made of spelt, rye or oats, then it does not need to be covered, as it does not precede the blessing of Hagafen.<sup>8</sup>

Meanwhile, I saw in Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchaso 47, he'arah 125, that Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach paskens that those who hold that we cover the mezonos products, is only relevant to the person making Kiddush (and others who are partaking of the wine). All other participants would not need to cover their mezonos, since they are not “shaming” the mezonos by listening to Kiddush.

---

> <sup>1</sup> [Peri Megadim 271 A”A 7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=171&hilite=); [Kitzur SHU”A 55:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.55.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Levushei Mordechaiy 1:46; Shvilei David 271; Orchos Rabbeinu See Piskeiy Teshuvos 271 footnote 184; 194
>
> <sup>2</sup> The reason: As the blessing of Mezonos foods precede that of Hagafen [See Admur in Seder Birchas Hanehnin 10:13-14], and hence its shame is to be covered just as by bread. [Levushei Mordechai ibid based on 3rd reason recorded in Admur and Poskim ibid] Likewise, as one of the reasons behind covering the bread is to show that the food was brought to the table for the sake of Shabbos [i.e. Yikra Deashabbasa]. Now, initially the custom was not to bring the food at all to the table prior to Kiddush due to this [see [Admur 271/17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); [Tur 271](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.271.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Tosafus Pesachim 100b; Sheilasos Yisro 54; Rashbam Pesachim ibid], and now that we bring it to the table, at the very least one must cover it, and there is no difference between the Challah and the other foods. [P”M ibid] Practically, this later reason seems to be negated by Admur, as in his conclusion he writes “The custom is to bring it initially before Kiddush and cover the bread until after Kiddush”;
>
> <sup>3</sup> See wording in Kitzur SHU”A ibid; See Piskeiy Teshuvos 271:19
>
> <sup>4</sup> Birchas Habayis 46:50; Shut Rav Akiva Yosef Shlezinger 95; Taamei Haminhagim Kuntrus Achron 365; See Ashel Avraham 271
>
> <sup>5</sup> The reason: As the concept of shame only really applies to bread which is the ehad of the emal, and not to Mezonos, even though technically its blessing precedes. [Poskim ibid]
>
> <sup>6</sup> Implication of Admur [271:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that “The custom is to bring it initially before Kiddush and cover the bread until after Kiddush”; See Hearos Ubiurim Tzemach Tzedek 7/257; See Tehila Ledavid 74; Ashel Avraham 282; Az Nidbaru 2:8; Piskeiy Teshuvos ibid
>
> <sup>7</sup> Simple implication of wording of Admur in [299:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.299.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) regarding if bread is on the table by Havdalah
>
> <sup>8</sup> Implication of Admur in Seder Birchas Hanehnin 10:13-14; [Peri Megadim A”A 211:7-8](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=146) on [M”A 211:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.211.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en); Birchas Habayis 13:9
>
> Implication of Admur: So is implied from Admur 10:13-14 which only mentions barley and wheat by Mezonos that has precedence over wine, and so is also implied from the next Halacha in which Admur emphasizes that Hamoitzi of all 5 grains has precedence to wine. Now, if it was already established in the previous Halacha that even Mezonos of the 5 grains has precedence to wine, then certainly Hamotzi would have precedence to wine and thus what would be the novelty of this ruling. Hence, one must conclude that wine has precedence to all grains which are not mentioned explicitly in the verse, which include spelt, rye and oats.
>
> Other opinions: Some Poskim rule that the Mezonos of all 5 grains have precedence to wine. [[Rama 211:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.211.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), as explained in [Mishneh Berurah 211:24]](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.211.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: Why can’t reasons one and two also apply to covering mezonos?

Comment: @JoelK I can only assume that the first two are related to the meal itself, whereas the third centres around the precedence of brochos?

Comment: @Dov mezonos is your meal here. קידוש במקום סעודה. The first reason applies to mezonos and even fruit. The second reason would probably apply only to something that requires lechem mishneh which arguably includes mezonos.